# How to use iframe src without http(s)

Tags: html, iframe

I'm currently trying to embed using an iframe. The site I'm embedding (embed.embed.embed.com/) doesn't have a protocol (http or https) I'm not sure why this is but it doesnt operate if a protocol is established.

My website is https://www.example.com

```
<iframe src="//embed.embed.embed.com/"></iframe>
```

This would return https://embed.embed.embed.com/ (which doesn't work - returns a 404).

```
<iframe src="embed.embed.embed.com/"></iframe>
```

This would return https://www.example.com/embed.embed.embed.com/

What can I prefix the src with in order to direct it to a root domain, without assuming a protocol? Is there even a way of doing this? If not with an iframe what other methods might be recommended?

Answer (score 0):

do you want like this,

```
<base href="http://example.com">

<iframe src="example.com"> </iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work, as it points it towards a http protocol.